# Laravel pivot with multiple columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi I have a problem with Laravel`s pivot table.

I have the following tables: students, courses and lessons.

The table lessons is connected with courses through a foreign key courses_id, and the tables students and courses are connected through a pivot courses_students.

So I can access the information through students like this:

```
//Students model
public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Courses::class,'courses_students','student_id', 'course_id')
        ->with('lessons');
}

//Courses model
public function lessons()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
}
```

This works completely fine for this kind of relationship, but I want to add a third column in the pivot with name lesson_id for the lessons table.

I am doing this because, sometimes I need to get a specific set of lessons from each course for each user.

I succeeded in doing so, by using a model courseStudent for the pivot table.

Using the model for pivot my calls became like this.

```
Student->with('courseStudent.courses')
    ->with('courseStudent.lessons')
    ->get();
```

This partially does what I need it to do, but I want to maintain the relation ship between courses and students.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Example from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)(go through Many To Many):

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

Pivot table is meant to use `belongsToMany` relationship on both entities.
So your students and courses should have it defined if you want pivot table between that is using eloquent default capacity.
As a side note pay attention on naming convention because that way you will reduce issues on minimum: pivot table should be `tableanamesingular_tablebnamesingular` where order is set by alphabetical order of tables' names (i.e. `post_user` Yes, `user_post` No).
Id fields in pivot table should be `tablenamesingular_id`.
You can set names however you want but this way you will have less unepected behavior in future using eloquent. All of this you have in [documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) and I recommend you go through it thoroughly.
Other way is to use dynamic properties for getting certain values. Example from docs:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->created_at;
}
```

If you would like to manually change values in pivot table, you should create separate model for it that would be connected with that entity/table (pay attention that pivot model extends Pivot as in example from docs rather than Model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class PostUser extends Pivot
{
    // other definitions related
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join for third relation:

```
public function courses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Courses::class,'courses_students','student_id', 'course_id')
    ->withPivot('lesson_id')
    ->join('lessons','lesson_id','=','lessons.id')
    ->select('lessons.id','lessons.title', ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the same pivot table for courses and lessons, you can to do something like this:

```
//Students model

public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Courses::class,'courses_students','student_id', 'course_id')
        ->whereNotNull('course_id');
}


public function lessons()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Lessons::class,'courses_students','student_id', 'lesson_id')
        ->whereNotNull('lesson_id');
}
```

Then just use it:

```
$courses = $student->courses;
$lessons = $student->lessons;
```

Comment: Indeed I could do this but I would like to have a relationship like this "student->course-lessons", to have all lessons grouped in their respective course.